# Why do TypedArrays have a static length property with value 3

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays, uint8array

I just came across [this gem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#Properties) when looking up some `Uint8Array` properties:

> **TypedArray.length**
>
> Length property whose value is 3.

I tried it and it is true!

[image: wtf]

What? Why does this exist?!

Comment: Run this in your console: `var x = new Uint8Array([17, -45.3]); console.log(x.length);`

Comment: Ha I knew someone would think I was asking how to get the correct length. That is not what I am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For functions, the length property is how many parameters are in its argument list. For the Uint8Array constructor, that number is 3.

```js
function example2 (a, b) {}
function example3 (a, b, c) {}

console.log(example2.length);
console.log(example3.length);
```

Regardless of the length property, any function can be passed any number of arguments, and the function can use or ignore all of them. So the length is just a hint about how many are likely to be used.

```js
// This function doesn't list any arguments, so it's length is 0
function example () {
  // ...but it uses 2 anyway.
  console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1])
}
console.log(example.length);
// .. and i can pass in more than 2, useless though it is.
example('first', 'second', 'third');
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes some vague sense!